# need to replace the blank value as 0

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

need to replace the blank column  into 0 
for example the table is 
[image]

i have tried this query to bring the output 
but it is taking more number of time because i have put this table in to procedure

instead of using 'case' can we bring the output with any other concept

```
select 
case when hail_n like '' then '0' else hail_n end as Hail_N, 
case when hail_s like '' then '0' else hail_s end as Hail_S,
case when hail_e like '' then '0' else hail_e end as Hail_E,
case when hail_w like '' then '0' else hail_w end as Hail_W,
case when wind_n like '' then '0' else wind_n end as Wind_N,
case when wind_s like '' then '0' else wind_s end as Wind_S,
case when wind_e like '' then '0' else wind_e end as Wind_E,
case when wind_w like '' then '0' else wind_w end as Wind_W
from vw_hail_wind_directions
```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is no magic; if you have 8 columns to output then you'll need to have 8 expressions to change the output in any way. (Have you considered normalization?)

A slightly less verbose approach would be:

```
SELECT 
  Hail_N = COALESCE(NULLIF(hail_n, ''),'0'),
  Hail_S = COALESCE(NULLIF(hail_s, ''),'0'),
  ...
FROM dbo.vw_hail_wind_directions; -- always use schema prefix and statement terminators
```

Comment: This approach also taking more number of time to execute. Do u have any other ideas

Comment: can u help me i need some other ideas

Comment: @Vineet if this is slow, it's the view, not the expressions you're applying to the output columns.

Comment: ya thats ok but can we bring that 0 instead of blank by using any other concept . If you said means it will be more helpfull for me

Comment: Sure, do it in the application. There isn't a faster way to do it in T-SQL, and I don't think there is a way with less code (unless you stuff those expressions into the view or populate the base table with 0 instead of an empty string in the first place).